# I can't power my RPi 3b with AA batteries

Tags: pi-3, power, battery

I'm trying to power my Pi 3 with 8x AA batteries wired to a 5V voltage regulator. I measured a voltage of 5.4V. I'm using the IO pins instead of the microUSB port.

The Pi powers on but doesn't work. The red led starts blinking. When I connect a monitor I see that it's stuck in a boot loop.

Shouldn't it be possible to power a Pi like this? Am I doomed to buy a proper battery?

Comment: Sanity check: Does the same Pi power up normally using a standard 2-3 A 5 V power supply?

Comment: Yup it does work with a 2A/5V supply.

Comment: It's definitely [possible](https://www.piborg.org/battborg) to run the Pi from AA batteries. What regulator are you using? The Pi 3 is more of a current hog than previous models, so it'll need to be fairly beefy.

Comment: Here are the specifications http://www.tme.eu/en/Document/57f67002a9a9de08fda68ad242b570b4/qdc2s-2405s.pdf

Comment: Which model of that are you using?

Comment: It's QDC1S-1205S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the voltage regulator you're using (the [QLT POWER QDC1S-1205S](http://www.tme.eu/en/Document/57f67002a9a9de08fda68ad242b570b4/qdc2s-2405s.pdf)) is only capable of supplying a maximum of 400mA. Just about all models of the Pi will require more current than that - the Pi 3 needs something like 5 times as much (between 2 and 3 amps is normal).

You may still be able to achieve your goal, but you'll need a regulator that can supply much more current. Something like the [TI LM1085-5.0](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1085.pdf) (which can provide up to 3A of output current) should work.